# Understanding how networkx count directed triangles

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to calculate clustering coefficient using clustering() from networkx. However, i'm getting some very bizarre outputs.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 1) ])
nx.clustering(G)
```

> Out: {1: 0.2777777777777778, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5, 5: 0}

I cannot understand how they obtain a clustering coefficient of 0.277 for node 1. There are only 3 edges between the neighbors of node 1. The formula networkx uses for directed networks is this:

[image: c_u = \frac{1}{deg^{tot}(u)(deg^{tot}(u)-1) - 2deg^{\leftrightarrow}(u)} T(u)]

where T(u) is the number of directed triangles through node u, degtot(u) is the sum of in degree and out degree of u and deg↔(u) is the reciprocal degree of u.

Going by the formula,

[image: T_u = {5 * 4 - 2} * 0.277777 = 5]

It is counting 5 directed triangles through node 1 when there should only be 3.

Am i missing something? or is my understanding of what a triangle is wrong?

Comment: I believe you have triangles 1-2-3, 1-3-4, 1-4-3, 4-1-3, and 3-4-1.  5, divided by (5 x 4 - 2 x 1) would be 5/18 or 0.277777.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why should triangle 4-1-3 and 3-4-1 be considered when I'm calculating the CC for node 1? If i'm looking at the edges between neighbours of node 1, shouldn't it just be 1-2-3, 1-3-4, 1-4-3?

Comment: No.  You're counting the number of triangles that go THROUGH node 1, not the number that START at node 1.